# Python: append/ extend method

Tags: python, append

Can someone explain me why after the for loop the list res is `['m']`?

```py
string = 'spam'
for x in string:
    res =[]
    res.extend(x)
print(res)
```

I expected the output to be `res = ['s', 'p', 'a', 'm']`

Comment: `str` is weird, due to the lack of a dedicated `char` type in Python. A `str` value acts like a container of 1-character `str` values.

Comment: `'s' == 'spam'[0] == 'spam'[0][0] == 'spam'[0][0][0] == ....` , no matter how many `[0]` you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are replacing the list object *each step of your loop*. The statement `res = []` creates a new, empty list object, then adds a single letter to that list.

Without the loop, this is what you are doing:

```
>>> x = 's'
>>> res = []
>>> res.extend(x)
>>> res
['s']
>>> x = 'p'
>>> res = []
>>> res.extend(x)
['p']
>>> x = 'a'
>>> res = []
>>> res.extend(x)
>>> res
['a']
>>> res = []
>>> x = 'm'
>>> res.extend(x)
>>> res
['m']
```

Create the list *outside* of the loop, **once**:

```
string = 'spam'
res = []
for x in string:
    res.extend(x)
print(res)
```

Now you don't keep replacing the list object with a new one each iteration of the `for` loop.

Again, removing the loop and doing the steps manually, now we have:

```
>>> res = []
>>> x = 's'
>>> res.extend(x)
>>> res
['s']
>>> x = 'p'
>>> res.extend(x)
>>> res
['s', 'p']
>>> x = 'a'
>>> res.extend(x)
>>> res
['s', 'p', 'a']
>>> x = 'm'
>>> res.extend(x)
>>> res
['s', 'p', 'a', 'm']
```

Not that you should be using `res.extend()` here; it only works because individual letters in `string` assigned to `x` are each also strings and even single-letter strings are still sequences. What you are really doing with `res.extend(x)` is the equivalent of `for element in x: res.append(element)`, but `x` will always have just one element.

So this would work too:

```
string = 'spam'
res = []
for x in string:
    res.append(x)
print(res)
```

or just extend `res` with the whole `string` value:

```
string = 'spam'
res = []
res.extend(string)
print(res)
```

or, if you just wanted a list of all the characters of a string, just use the `list()` function:

```
string = 'spam'
res = list(string)
print(res)
```

`list()` does exactly what you wanted to do with your loop: create an empty list, loop over the input, and add each element to the new list, which is then returned:

```
>>> string = 'spam'
>>> list(string)
['s', 'p', 'a', 'm']
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll never get that output because for every iteration of the loop, you are setting `res = []` and therefore only the last iteration will work by extending the blank list with `'m'`.

The fixed code looks like this:

```py
string = 'spam'
res = []
for x in string:
    res.extend(x)
print(res)
```

Another note is that you probably should use `.append` in this case. `.extend` is for appending an entire iterable but since you are only adding one element at a time it isn't necessary. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/what-is-the-difference-between-pythons-list-methods-append-and-extend) for a good explanation.

Also a last note here is that you'll want to be careful with editing python code outside of plain text or code editors. You're using some leading and trailing apostrophes `‘’` instead of regular `''` which will cause you trouble at some point.

Answer (score 0):

You are always re-initializing the `res` list in the for-loop, that is why in the last iteration of the loop the list is initialized to `[]` an empty list and the last letter is added to it.

```
string = 'spam'
res =[]
for x in string:
    res.extend(x)
print(res)
```

or to make it simple, use the `list` builtin which takes an ***iterable*** like a string and converts it into an ***list*** object:

```
>>> list('spam')
['s', 'p', 'a', 'm']
```

Answer (score 0):

You are resetting res every time inside the loop. You need to use this-

```
string = ‘spam’
res =[]
for x in string:   
    res.extend(x)
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is simplest way:

```
string = 'spam'
res = list(string)
```